Testing an Update a Post function
I'm not really sure about how to update blog posts based on my code. I've been using method-based views.
def create_post(request):
    form_class = PostForm
    template = 'addpost.html'

    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        content = request.POST.get("content")
        user_id = request.POST.get("author")

        if request.user.has_perm("posts.add_post"):
            Post.objects.create(
                title=title,
                content=content,
                author=User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            )
        else:
            pass

    return render(request, template)

def edit_post(request):
    form_class = PostForm
    template = 'editpost.html'

    if request.method == "PATCH":
        form = form_class(request.PATCH)
        Title = request.PATCH.GET("title")
        Content = request.PATCH.GET("content")
        User_id = request.PATCH.GET("author")

    if request.user.has_perm("posts.update_post") and (User_id == User.pk):
        Post.objects.update(
            title=Title,
            content=Content,
            author=User.objects.get(pk=User_id)
        )
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, template)


For the update_post method, do I use PATCH, UPDATE, or a POST request in this scenario?
Keep in mind that I'm also using this method for testing purposes as well.
Here's the Pytest Code:
class TestPermissions:
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_post_add_contributor_group_permission(db):
        client = Client()

        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username="testuser",
            email="test@example.com",
            password="pass123"
        )

        

        post_data = {
            "title": "Post Title",
            "content": "Post Content",
            "author": user.id
        }

        group = Group.objects.create(name="Contributor")
        client.login(username="testuser", password="pass123")

        response = client.post(reverse("add_post"), post_data)

        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert Post.objects.all().count() == 0

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        permission = Permission.objects.get(
            content_type=content_type,
            codename__icontains="add"
        )

        group.permissions.add(permission)
        user.groups.add(group)

        response = client.post(reverse("add_post"), post_data)

        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert Post.objects.all().count() == 0


    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_post_update_contributor_group_permission(db):
        client = Client()

        user = User.objects.create_user(
             username="testuser",
            email="test@example.com",
            password="pass123"
        )

        post_data = {
            "title": "Post Title",
            "content": "Post Content",
            "author": user.id
        }

        group = Group.objects.create(name="Contributor")
        client.login(username="testuser", password="pass123")

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        permission = Permission.objects.get(
            content_type=content_type,
            codename__icontains="add"
        )

        group.permissions.add(permission)
        user.groups.add(group)

    
        response = client.post(reverse("add_post"), post_data)

        updated_data = {
            "title": "Updated Post Title",
            "content": "Updated Post Content",
            "author": user.id
        }
        response = client.patch('edit_post//1', updated_data)

        assert response.status_code == 200

I have been using both patch and update without any success. Is there anyone who can give me a clue here as to make updates?
EDIT: To clarify, I have an issue trying to pass this function test.
Some of the solutions that I have tried are the following:
Do I use UPDATE or PATCH HTTP Request in this instance?
Also, as works as it is, it provides me with a 404 response as opposed to the desired 200.
There are other solutions I have tried to go over other solutions: One solution I tried to do is to use 'reverse'. Here's what that looks like:
response = client.patch(reverse('edit_post/1'), updated_data)

This results in an "'edit_post/1' not found for reverse".

I don't think this is really answerable. You're asking "how does my code work" but we have no idea what "without any success" means. You should probably walk through this with a debugger or some print statements. Once you determine what the specific issue is- you can open up a specific question.

The issue is that I have a few questions:
Do I use an HTTP PATCH or UPDATE request?
I've been trying to make the Update posts test pass.
The code that I currently have gives me a 404 response. I need to have the test post.
For example, I have been using reverse for instance:
response = client.patch(reverse('edit_post/1'), updated_data)

Which gives me an "'edit_post/1' is not found". Even though I have it as the URL patterns. I have used the post id as a PK.
Nothing seems to work so far.
